# Lower Bound for Area of Topological Annulus

Tags: general-topology, geometry, area

*Problem*
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed topological annulus with inner boundary $\partial_iA$ and outer boundary $\partial_oA$ such that the origin $O$ is interior to the region bounded by $\partial_iA$.
Define line segment $L$ as $$L=\{(x,0)|x=r_i+tr_o,t\in[0,1]\}$$ where $(r_i,0)\in\partial_iA$ and $(r_o,0)\in\partial_oA$.

If $L$ is the shortest line segment between $\partial_iA$ and $\partial_oA$, then the area of $A$ is known to be $$\mu(A)\geq\pi(r_o^2-r_i^2)$$

*Idea*
In polar coordinate, if $\partial_iA$ and $\partial_oA$ can be expressed as $(\rho_i(\theta),\theta)$ and $(\rho_o(\theta),\theta)$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then $$\mu(A)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}(\rho_o^2 -\rho_i^2)d\theta$$
If we take the minimum of the expression $(\rho_o^2 -\rho_i^2)$ which is indeed $(r_o^2-r_i^2)$, then we arrive at the answer.

But, the problem is that the annulus can be so 'wobbly' that we cannot express the boundaries nicely with parameter $\theta$. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to be done. The area of $A$ can be any positive number whatsoever, even if you restrict $A$ so that the line segment 
$$L = [r_i,r_0] \times \{0\}
$$ 
in your formula is indeed equal to the intersection of $A$ with the non-negative $x$-axis $[0,\infty) \times \{0\}$.

For example, to make $\text{Area}(A)$ as small as possible, take any circle $C$ centered on the origin and intersecting $L$ in a single point, and then take $A$ to be an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $L \cup C$.